# PrimeFaces 3.4.2 / 3.5 makes ajax requests wait too long in my browser IE and Firefox

Tags: java, javascript, performance, jsf, primefaces

I have a JSF / PrimeFaces webapplication. I needed to PrimeFaces (security issue) upgrade to 3.4.2 from current PF 2.x.
I followed the Migration guide for upgrade 2.x to 3.x implementation.
I experience a slow request-repsonse in my browser.
I was able to determine the bottleneck. It seemed to be client-side. 
I am guessing it's something with PF 3.4.2 and javascript. Most of my Ajax calls (originating from PF client widgets) are the ones which takes too long to receive a response/ to render.

Has anyone experienced this situation before?

PS I have an (older) 1.8.13-ui jQuery JS implementation too in my code base.

Comment: It's hard to analyze the problem without any code. Please provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) in order to get help.

Comment: You say that you are manually importing jQuery by yourself?

Comment: Was the performance OK prior to the upgrade?

Comment: Hola Luiggi, I agree with your observation. Unfortunately this issue is difficult to pinpoint, at least to a specific code. We had a perfectly performing webapp, but after having made changes for the upgrade from 2.2.1 to 3.0.1 we experienced very bad client-side (JS/Ajax) performing code. I can explain which procedures I have taken in the process of upgrade.

Comment: Hola Luiggi, I agree with your observation. Unfortunately this issue is difficult to pinpoint, at least to a specific code. We had a perfectly performing webapp, but after having made changes for the upgrade from 2.2.1 to 3.0.1 we experienced very bad client-side (JS/Ajax) performing code. I can explain which procedures I have taken in the process of upgrade. I followed the migration manual 2.x --> 3.0. I had to download the Sam theme since it is no longer the default theme in 3.0. So I included the condigsettings in my web.xml (context-param). I followed the guide. Ajax calls are problematic.

Comment: Hello Partlov, Well actually I did not add jQuery. I mean I have seen that there is also jQuery UI being loaded in HTML. This is the only "foreign" code that is being used in the browser, besides any other PF related JS scripts. We dont even have our own JS written code. So I wondering what could be the problem, if the source of the problem is JS...?

Comment: Hi Anthony, Yes before the upgrade we did not have any noticeable performance problem. We changed to 3.0.1 and experience very slow Ajax calls. Ajax requests take seconds (3+ sec) to complete.